# changing big file with memory limit 20mb

Tags: java, memory, io, nio, large-files

I want to delete repeating number from big txt file, where the first line is number of sorted numbers in line, but have a memory limit - 20 mb. I read the article [How to Read a Large File](https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file) and try to use BufferedWriter, but the process is needed more than 20 mb. 
Help me pls.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeleteRepeatingNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(
                new FileInputStream("input.txt"), "UTF-8");
             Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
                     new OutputStreamWriter(
                             new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int prevInt = 0;

            if (n != 0) {
                prevInt = sc.nextInt();
                writer.write(String.valueOf(prevInt));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                int next = sc.nextInt();
                if (next != prevInt) {
                    writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    writer.write(String.valueOf(next));
                    prevInt = next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
21
2
4
8
8
8
9
11
11
11
11
11
11
13
14
15
16
222
222
222
222
222
```

Comment: 20mb for the whole jvm ? This will be difficult. How do you start the jvm, which error occurs ?

Comment: its only for buffer

Comment: Where do you see that more than 20mb are used ? I don't understand your problem

Comment: Where do you see that more than 20mb are used ? I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if 20mb will be enough just to start up the JVM, but there from the program perspective we can reduce the memory footprint, using these ways.

Well there can be two solutions to this problem:

1. You need to know numbers so you can check for duplicacy.
   Read the file line by line, and push the number into a HashMap. If hashmap.containsKey returns a true, you can assume its been duplicated. 
   **Benefit of this is one iteration is enough to solve the use-case, but 20MB memory limit can be breached if numbers are a lot unique.**
2. You can read first number from the file and then iterate through all rows in the file again line by line and delete the duplicate occurrence. And then you read the next record from the file and iterate again.
   **Good bit: 20mb memory limit would not be a concern, downside the number of iterations would increase which will be equal to number of unique numbers.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Grand thanks. I updated the issue with example. If I know the number of sorted numbers, is it possible to read first 200 lines, sort and write, clean the memory System.gc(), then to read next 200 lines, sort and write etc. But how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If you could show me your resource, I can help you more effectively. But I think you can try this first.

```html
public class DeleteRepeatingNumbers {

 public static void deleteRepeatingNumber() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("resources\\RepeatingNumberTest.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
   Set<Integer> dontRepeatedNumbers = new HashSet<>();
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
    dontRepeatedNumbers.add(sc.nextInt());
   }
   dontRepeatedNumbers.stream().forEach((Integer number) -> {
    sb.append(String.valueOf(number));
    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   });
  } catch (IOException e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }
  
  try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("resources\\RepeatingNumberTest_Output.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
   writer.write(sb.toString());
  } catch (IOException e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
}
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thank you for spent time. I added first line deleting            if(sc.hasNext()) sc.nextInt() and not adding separator in first line:             Iterator<Integer> iter = dontRepeatedNumbers.iterator();
            if(iter.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(iter.next());
                iter.remove();
            }

Comment: But this takes over 20 mb too.

Comment: Also I forgot to write that the first line is number of sorted numbers. For example:

Comment: 21
2
4
8
8
8
9
11
11
11
11
11
11
13
14
15
16
222
222
222
222
222

Comment: In my opinion, you can reduce the buffer size by separating to 2 parts. First you read the file, perform your logic and put result to a Strung Builder. Then you write all data in String Builder to the output file.
I think it will reduce a lot of buffer size. 
But about the limitation (20 Mb), it depends on your input.